# WooCommerce - Global $product is returning value null

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My code is:

```
function sync_on_product_save($new_status, $old_status, $post) {
     global $post;
     global $product;

 if( 
        $old_status != 'publish' 
        && $new_status == 'publish' 
        && !empty($post->ID) 
        && in_array( $post->post_type, 
            array( 'product') 
            )
        ) {         

        print_R($product);
}
}

add_action('transition_post_status', 'sync_on_product_save', 10, 3);
```

I want to pass the product price, sku, description, and name to third-party API.

Please help me.

Comment: What do you need it for? The 3rd argument of your function contains the post data.

Comment: As Jacob mentioned, the `$post` object is passed via the action and through that you pretty much have access to what you need. However, to answer the question about the `$product` object specifically, you need to give it a product ID (which is the post ID) to have it contain anything where you're trying to access it. See my answer below which provides a solution using the product object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `$product` object does not exist where you're trying to access it (when you're hitting "publish" in the editor).

As Jacob Peattie mentioned in the comments, you could probably get it all from the `$post` object. But, you can get the `$product` object from the `$post->ID` and then use the "get_" methods available in the object to get the values you need.

Here's your revised code for getting these values via `$product`:

```
function sync_on_product_save( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    if ( 
        $old_status != 'publish' 
        && $new_status == 'publish' 
        && ! empty( $post->ID ) 
        && in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'product' ) )
    ) {         

        // Get the product object for this ID:
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID );

        // Use "get_" methods for values:
        $product_sku   = $product->get_sku();
        $product_name  = $product->get_name();
        $product_price = $product->get_price();
        $product_desc  = $product->get_description();

        // Do what you need for 3rd party here...
    }
}

add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'sync_on_product_save', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: There's no reason to use global $post or $product in this code. If anything it could make `$post` incorrect. Just use the post object passed as a parameter.

Comment: I agree - I hadn't really looked at that as I was focused on the other part of his code.  But that should come out (editing now).

Comment: My Problem is solved. I use hook woocommerce_process_product_meta instead of  transition_post_status.
Thanks for your response.

Comment: @butlerblog Perfect! Thank you.